# Where can I see the code for the AWS SDK function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

For example, When I use this function like this

```
// snippet-start:[s3.JavaScript.buckets.createBucket]
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

// Create the parameters for calling createBucket
var bucketParams = {
  Bucket : process.argv[2]
};

// call S3 to create the bucket
s3.createBucket(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.Location);
  }
});
```

**I want to see the code** that implements the function. When I looked at the AWS SDK code, I couldn't go deeper than [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/clients/s3.d.ts#L31).

Where can I see the code for the AWS SDK function?

Comment: Note: the code you've shown, while valid, is not typically how you would write this code using modern JavaScript and the async AWS SDK functions. Specifically you'd use `const/let` rather than `var` and you'd use the promisified SDK calls e.g. `await s3.createBucket(params).promise()`. Also, you're using AWS JS SDK v2, which is still supported, but be aware there's now a v3 SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.d.ts` files are not code, they are only [type definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html).

If you look at the `s3.js` file that is next to that `s3.d.ts` file you've already found, you will see that it calls `require('../lib/services/s3')`.

Look in [that file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/services/s3.js) to find the code.